# how to get inserted object id in jongo with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, jongo

Account entity

```
public class Account 
{       
    @MongoObjectId
    private String _id;       
    private String name;    
    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }    
    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }   
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class JongoExample {<br>
   MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(); // code to connect with database
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("kommboxj");
Jongo jongo = new Jongo(db);<br>
MongoCollection accountCollection = jongo.getCollection("account");
Account account = new Account();<br>
account.setName("rks");<br>
String accountIdMongo = (String) accountCollection.insert(account).getUpsertedId();}
```

Here I found acountIdMongo is null, don't know how to get it, here I want inserted account ObjectId.

Comment: Found solution. After use of @MongoObjectId annotation in entity, its auto mapping, now i am able to get by account.getId() after insert method. No need to upsertedId

Comment: Please put your solution as an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

For me this helped:

[Jongo Starter Project](http://www.lordofthejars.com/2014/09/java-ee-mongodb-with-apache-tomee-and.html)

Based on the above the _id in **Color.java** would be:

```
@MongoObjectId
private String _id;
```

and then in **PersistenceHandler.java** in the **insert** method the  **Object** returned would contain the inserted object in the Mongo collection with _id populated.

```
public static Object insert(MongoCollection mongoCollection, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
  final Iterable<Parameter> params = Reflection.params(method, args);
  final Parameter parameter = params.iterator().next();

  Object value = parameter.getValue();
  if (value == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(parameter.getType().getSimpleName() + " object is null");

  mongoCollection.insert(value);

  return value;
}
```